# Tkinter Frame Resize one axis

Tags: python, resize, tkinter

I have a tkinter frame that I want to automatically resize on the Y axis but remain a constant width as I add label widgets to it.

To keep the X-size constant I am using `grid_propogate(False)` but that keeps the whole thing a constant size.

How can I set the frame to resize in this manner?

Thanks

Comment: should be spelled `grid_propagate`, for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out

Made a larger frame that encompassed the space that my frame could fill if maxed out and used `pack(fill=X`) and `pack_propagate(False)` to make the inner frame conform to the X dimension of the outer frame while not changing it.  I then could add lines to the innerframe as needed with it maintaining it's X size:

```
OuterFrame = Frame(root, height=500, width=400)
InnerFrame = Frame(OuterFrame, borderwidth=3, relief=RAISED)
InnerFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

# stuff that goes in the y-resizing InnerFrame

OuterFrame.pack_propogate(False)
OuterFrame.pack()
```

Comment: Actually, it's spelled `pack_propagate`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very ugly solution to me, (hopefully someone will come along with something better):

```
import Tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
f=tk.Frame(root,width=100,height=300)
f.grid_propagate(False)
f.grid(row=0,column=0)
def resize(evt):
    f.update_idletasks()
    height=f.winfo_reqheight()
    f.grid_propagate(False)
    if(evt.width!=100) or (evt.height!=height):
        f.configure(width=100,height=height)
    print "HERE", evt.width,height

f.bind('<Configure>',resize)

#Just some stupid (ugly) code to update the size of the widget at runtime.
def add_label():
    f.grid_propagate(True)
    lbl=tk.Label(f,text='   %d                   Hello!'%(add_label.row))
    lbl.grid(column=0,row=add_label.row)
    add_label.row+=1

add_label.row=0

b=tk.Button(root,text="Add label",command=add_label)
b.grid(row=1,column=0)
root.mainloop()
```